# video.js how do I make subtitle visible by default?

Tags: video.js

I used same markup as on example-demo page, but default parameter doesn't really work. I don't see any subtitle autoplay. I have to go manually to subtitle selection and choose the track.

```
    <track kind="subtitles" src="" srclang="en" label="English"  />
    <track kind="subtitles" src="" srclang="it" label="Italian" default />
```

What am I doing wrong? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript(jQuery) to trigger click event for the caption menu automatically when the player is ready. This will display the caption without clicking it manually.

```
videojs("vdoPlayer", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
  $("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(2).trigger('click');
});
```

You might have to change the eq() value depending on which menu item you are clicking. use console.log($("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(2).text()); to identify which menu is which.

Comment: This only works for me in Firefox. IE10 and Chrome can't seem to find li.vjs-menu-item I have tried changing the eq() index, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. If you've gotten this to work in the other big two browsers, I'd love to hear how.

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me on iPad (Chrome, Safari) and Windows 7 PC (FF, Chrome):

```
<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default></track>
```

I'm using videojs 4.6.2, maybe it was fixed since this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I’m experiencing the same behaviour with latest video.js Version 4.1.

**Default subtitles were visible in Version 3.x – they are not anymore in the 4.x version!** User has to manually click subtitle icon and select the subtitle language in order for the subtitles to be visible!
Default parameter is set exactly the same way as it was with 3.x version which was properly showing subtitles without user manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

The default parameter doesn't appear to do anything in 4.1.0 right now. There is an issue filed for it [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/656).

Additionally - from my understanding of the API, there's not a great way (without compiling your own player with more track functionality exposed via exports.js) to programatically choose the default track you want in a 'safe' way right now either.

My recommendation would be to un-comment the line referred to in the bug, do some testing, and (assuming it all works) submit a pull request to the videojs repo enabling default track selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `srclang="en"` from the English subtitles. While it is a bug, removing that seems to have fixed the issue for the commenter 'Crixo' on this [issue page](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/511#issuecomment-19000683).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can turn it on by default like this:

```
const videoJsOptions: VideoJsPlayerOptions = {
    ...
    tracks: [
      {
        src: `/films/${props.film.id}/subtitles.vtt`,
        kind: "captions",
        srclang: "en",
        label: "English",
        default: true,
      },
    ],
  };
```